# "Installation of the application failed. Run time error has eccured. Fix the capabilities in WMAppManifest.xml file."

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I was building this simple application for WP8. Everything was working fine until today I had to add a new capability to the manifest file to allow access to sensors. I just used graphical editor to tick `ID_CAP_SENSORS`. Now every time I try to deploy my app I get:

```
Installation of the application failed. Run time error has eccured. Fix the capabilities in WMAppManifest.xml file.
```

Here is my whole manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsphone/2012/deployment" AppPlatformVersion="8.0">
  <DefaultLanguage xmlns="" code="en-US" />
  <App xmlns="" ProductID="{445cf5dd-14ec-4542-a44b-3d5600c1a6e5}" Title="BitCoinTile" RuntimeType="Silverlight" Version="1.0.0.1" Genre="apps.normal" Author="Wiktor Zdziechowski" Description="This very simple application helps you to keep track of BitCoin price." Publisher="XXX" PublisherID="{38b628a8-f9ec-4f05-a22e-5eba9ffe686e}">
    <IconPath IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\Tiles\FlipCycleTileMedium.png</IconPath>
    <Capabilities>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_SENSORS" />
    </Capabilities>
    <Tasks>
      <DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml" />
    </Tasks>
    <Tokens>
      <PrimaryToken TokenID="BitCoinTailToken" TaskName="_default">
        <TemplateFlip>
          <SmallImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\Tiles\FlipCycleTileMedium.png</SmallImageURI>
          <Count>0</Count>
          <BackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\Tiles\FlipCycleTileMedium.png</BackgroundImageURI>
          <Title>BitCoinTile</Title>
          <BackContent>
          </BackContent>
          <BackBackgroundImageURI>
          </BackBackgroundImageURI>
          <BackTitle>
          </BackTitle>
          <DeviceLockImageURI>
          </DeviceLockImageURI>
          <HasLarge>
          </HasLarge>
        </TemplateFlip>
      </PrimaryToken>
    </Tokens>
    <Extensions>
      <Extension ExtensionName="LockScreen_Notification_TextField" ConsumerID="{111DFF24-AA15-4A96-8006-2BFF8122084F}" TaskID="_default" />
    </Extensions>
    <ScreenResolutions>
      <ScreenResolution Name="ID_RESOLUTION_WVGA" />
      <ScreenResolution Name="ID_RESOLUTION_WXGA" />
      <ScreenResolution Name="ID_RESOLUTION_HD720P" />
    </ScreenResolutions>
    <Requirements>
      <Requirement Name="ID_REQ_GYROSCOPE" />
    </Requirements>
  </App>
</Deployment>
```

My manifest file seems ok to me. I have no idea how to debug that. Compiler is not even showing were exactly I have the problem. I will be very glad for any hint.

Comment: Does your phone have a gyroscope as per the `Requirement`? Or is this failure on the Emulator?

Comment: Yes It does have a gyroscope (HTC 8S). I don't have an option to test it on virtual machine though. I'm running on Virtual Box. That wasn't a problem so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTC 8S **doesn't** have a gyroscope (I've just tried one). That is the error you get if you specify:

```
<Requirements>
  <Requirement Name="ID_REQ_GYROSCOPE" />
</Requirements>
```

and try running the app on a dev phone without a gyroscope.

Of course the App Store would hide any such apps so the HTC 8S wouldn't be able to download them.

Comment: I had the same error message, but in my case it was the requirement `<Requirement Name="ID_REQ_MAGNETOMETER" />` stopping the Emulator working. I have a mock Magnetometer implementation that I use in the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Wow! After having wasted some time trying to solve this problem I eventually solved it by just keeping **only** those capabilities which I am actually using, no less, no more! In my case I only needed internet permission so here is how the capabilities part of my WMAppManifest.xml looks now

```
<Capabilities>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
</Capabilities>
```