# Wp8 app Deployment Error 0x81030110 in the emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, deployment

I was developed wp8 app and signed my app with enterprise certificate using powershell.After successfully signed and i was trying to deploy my signed app in emulator,but i was received the error, [image]

when i googled about this error they stated that **Failed to install the application. Runtime error has occurred. Capabilities WMAppManifest.xml file located in the attribute content is incorrect.**
and they referred this site [link](http://blog.jongallant.com/2010/05/0x81030110-windows-phone.html#.UdU83mJuQ6E).but i was not able to found the proper solution.kindly help me to get rid of this problem

Answer (score 1):

After having wasted some time trying to solve this problem I eventually solved it by just keeping **only** those capabilities which I am actually using, no less, no more! In my case I only needed internet permission so here is how the capabilities part of my WMAppManifest.xml looks now

```
<Capabilities>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
</Capabilities>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error a few days ago when I had the “ID_CAP_GAMERSERVICES” checked for an APP that did not require the manifest. Have you tried un-checking all capabilities that you are not exposing in your app? Capabilities such as “ID_CAP_INTEROPSERVICES”, “ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER” etc. are included by default in a windows phone 8 project.

If this does not resolve the issue perhaps post your app’s manifest file capability section?

Comment: In my app, I used webbrowser so i just enabled ID_CAP_NETWORKING and ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT

Comment: could you pls tell me the procedure you followed while deploying the application

Comment: can you post the content of your WMAppManifest.xml file?

Comment: The Capablities Section are <Capabilities>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT" />
    </Capabilities>

Comment: Please post the content of the whole file, including the following information, Handset name you are trying to deploy too, SDK version eg 7.0, 7.1 etc, see if [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372792/installation-of-the-application-failed-run-time-error-has-eccured-fix-the-cap[/link] also helps