# Trying to deploy on Windows Phone Emulator returns 0x8103010B

Tags: mobile, deployment, windows-phone-8.1, temenos-quantum

I am having problemas when using 'Windows Phone Application Deployment Tool (8.1)' to install a xap into the emulators, on every emulator i am getting the same error.

Already done:

- Reinstall the sdk;
- Reinstall the emulators;
- UPDATE: Tested on a developer unlocked phone and I an getting the same error

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wp8 app Deployment Error 0x81030110 in the emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17467430/wp8-app-deployment-error-0x81030110-in-the-emulator)

Comment: don't think it's a duplicate, the error code is different